# powerdot produces vertical clock in smartboard papersize

Tags: powerdot

I'm trying to compile a basic page that includes only the title.

I've added the clock via global options.

When I compile it in {present, landscape} settings in "screen" paper size, everything is just fine.

However, it produces a vertical clock when compiled in "smartboard" paper size.

During compilation I execute latex > dvips > ps2pdf in this order.

How could I fix it?

I add the minimal non-working code below.

```
\documentclass[paper=smartboard, style=horatio, orient=landscape, size=17pt, clock]{powerdot}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible a bug?

Comment: I suppose it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `powerdot`. In the code that positions the clock there is a check for orientation (line 653 in `powerdot.cls`) that incorrectly results in the clock being rotated for the `smartboard` setting.

You can patch that line with the `xpatch` package to set the rotation to 0 degrees for files where you use the `smartboard` option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=smartboard, style=horatio, orient=landscape, size=17pt, clock]{powerdot}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\pd@sl@de}{\ifnum\pd@orient=\z@ 90\else 0\fi}{\ifnum\pd@orient=\z@ 0\else 0\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was right there was a bug. Powerdot similar to beamer for my humble opinion is old package, and I think that only few people use it. My compliments.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn. I wonder around those lines for a while to see what was wrong, but I couldn't figure it out.